# How to change directory security attributes using InstallShield?

Tags: installation, installshield

I'd like to change the security attribute of a directory that InstallShield creates under the `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` - can someone please advise on how to do that during the installation process?

It's a script-defined folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also just easily call Windows commands "CACLS.EXE" or "ICACLS.EXE" -both are easy command line tool, e.g.

icacls file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
 - Will grant the user Administrator Delete and Write DAC
   permissions to file

Comment: Yes, I've looked at those, but from what I understand, icacls is not present on XP and cacls is deprecated on Vista. And who knows what will happen on the next Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Under InstallShield 2008 it's

```
Installation Designer > Components > [somecomponent] > Destination Permissions
```

Note that the directory properties are attached to the component, while individual File permissions are set under the 'Files' node

This assumes you are letting InstallShield / Windows Installer handle directory creation. If you're creating the directory in a script then things start getting tricky if you need  to ensure a clean uninstall.

Comment: Thank you. I do create the directory in the script - is there a way to set permissions then? And what would be the problems with uninstalling?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer for this - on this page: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isp_os.htm there's an ntperm.zip archive which contains a script that seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether a Installshield builtin function exists for that. The simple solution is to create a DLL that does the real work of manipulating the security attributes and call it once the directory is created.

Typically, one might want to change the access so that everyone is able to read/write to the whole directory or file(s) within it.

Comment: Yes, it could work as a work-around, but I'm hoping for something built-in :) If nothing comes up, then that would be the only solution. Or to use calcs.