# Modifing Values In App.Config Show Error

Tags: c#, app-config, file-permissions

I am trying to save values in app.config and modifying at the run time.

I created a setup and deployed on different machines.

It works fine where the user has read and write permission in the folder.

However the below error occurs where the user does not have permission to read and write in the folder.

I am wondering why this is happening ?

[image: Error]

Comment: As this file is being deployed as a part of your application. So you may have the possibility to modify the access permissions of this file  during the installation itself.

Comment: can you please tell me any link to modify permissions ? @Ramashankar

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137870/how-to-change-directory-security-attributes-using-installshield